# Changing multiple text strings using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a modified VBA macro I found on extendoffice.com to change input specified strings within cells.  The macro works great; I highlight the cells I want analyzed and it asks for an input. The specified string is then colored blue lettering and bolded.   I'm hoping that I can alter this a little so that the macro can find multiple strings without having to be ran individually for every new string.

Tried: for i for UserList // UserList = cell A1 with the strings separated by commas

```
Sub HighlightStrings()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cFnd As String
Dim xTmp As String
Dim x As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim y As Long
cFnd = InputBox("Enter the text string to highlight")
y = Len(cFnd)
For Each Rng In Selection
  With Rng
    m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, cFnd))
    If m > 0 Then
      xTmp = ""
      For x = 0 To m - 1
        xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, cFnd)(x)
        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.Bold = True
        xTmp = xTmp & cFnd
      Next
    End If
  End With
Next Rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want to bold and color blue the words "thrombus", "stroke", "anticoagulation therapy"; to do so, the macro needs to be run three times.  I would like to be able to make a list of strings and let the macro run through the list, so I only have to run it once.

I have very little coding knowledge and I thank you for your help.

Comment: You could have the search items entered as a string separated by commas, split that by comma into an array and loop through each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make very minor changes to your sub to allow it to accept an argument and then call it in a loop:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim MyList As String, arr, a
    MyList = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="give me comma-separated text strings", Type:=2)
    arr = Split(MyList, ",")
    For Each a In arr
        Call HighlightStrings(a)
    Next a
End Sub

Sub HighlightStrings(cFnd As Variant)
        'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim xTmp As String
        Dim x As Long
        Dim m As Long
        Dim y As Long

        y = Len(cFnd)
        For Each Rng In Selection
          With Rng
            m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, cFnd))
            If m > 0 Then
              xTmp = ""
              For x = 0 To m - 1
                xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, cFnd)(x)
                .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.Bold = True
                xTmp = xTmp & cFnd
              Next
            End If
          End With
        Next Rng
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create collection and loop through it. Sorry it's a bit of a mess but I'm a bit busy now and can't clean up the code as I'd like to but it works; input box will keep popping up util it's either left blank, or 'cancel' is clicked:

```
Sub HighlightStrings()
    'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cFnd As String
    Dim xTmp As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim myCol As New Collection

    Do
        ib = InputBox("Enter the text string to highlight")
        If ib <> vbNullString Then myCol.Add ib
    Loop While ib <> vbNullString

    For Each mc In myCol
        cFnd = mc
        y = Len(cFnd)
        For Each Rng In Selection
            With Rng
            m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, cFnd))
                If m > 0 Then
                    xTmp = ""
                    For x = 0 To m - 1
                        xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, cFnd)(x)
                        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.Bold = True
                        xTmp = xTmp & cFnd
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        Next Rng
    Next mc

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```